# NSTimer Won't Invalidate in ViewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

-void()timerMethod
{
    ...some stuff
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(refreshScreen:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-void(refreshScreen:id(sender)
{
...some stuff that calls other methods one of which calls timerMethod to continue the process
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.timer invalidate];
   self.timer = nil;
}
```

When I move to a new VC, viewWillDisappear is called and I confirm that 
1/ timer is invalidated (using [self.timer isValid].
2/ We are on the main thread (using [NSThread isMainThread]
3/ timer is Nil

The timer itself when created is also confirmed on the main thread.

Some seconds later on the other VC, the timer calls the "refreshScreen" method regardless of the above.

I have checked that the invalidate within timerMethod is invalidating with each pass.  I am doing this to ensure that more than 1 timer is not created.  Breakpoints show that although the timer goes invalid and nil upon exit, once it calls "refreshScreen" again it has reestablished the timer and is no longer nil despite the fact that its VC was dismissed.

Comment: Don't you need to add [super viewWillDisappear:animated]?

Comment: Unfortunately adding that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've simplified the code to the point where the problem doesn't exist.  Running that code on a simple test app that has a navigation controller and two view controllers doesn't exhibit the problem.

Comment: I am not sure what else to add.  The other stuff doesn't call or use the timer in anyway.  I did a find on "self.timer" to ensure this wasn't called elsewhere.  The refresh routine calls some methods that does some prep and then the method that contains the timer is called (timerMehod I describe above).  I figured a bunch of code setting unrelated variables and screen elements would just create noise.

Comment: I agree that you don't want too much noise, but the only theory I can come up with is that `refreshScreen` is somehow still running when the other VC is presented, so that `timerMethod` is called *after* `viewWillDisappear`.  This would imply that `refreshScreen` has code running on a background thread, and the background thread posts a message on the main queue to call `timerMethod`. That's a real stretch I know :) but that's the best I can come up with, without seeing `refreshScreen`.

Comment: On second thought, maybe the thing to do is put an `NSLog` just before the call to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. That may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: You are right!  I put a breakpoint in ViewWillDisappear and another in the timer method.  VWD was called and then the timer.  So that is the cause.  I need to investigate but wanted to send a quick and huge thank you to start!